# Maximal ideals in Tate algebra $K\left<t\right>$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-spaces

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed nonarchimedean field, $\mathbb{B}=\{ a\in K: |a|\leq 1 \}$ be the unit ball, and let $\text{Sp }K\left<t\right>$ be the maximal spectrum of the Tate algebra $K\left<t\right>$. I know $B$ is natural bijection with $\text{Sp }K\left<t\right>$. But if we consider the principal ideal $I=(t-a)$ with $|a|>1$. It looks like the ideal would correspond to the point $a$, which is outside the unit disk. But then what is this ideal?

Comment: Why don't you define what is the Tate algebra? Obviously $1-t/a$ is a unit if $|a|>1$

Comment: @reuns You are right. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @user393795 Don't apologize for implying you're stupid. (You're not.)